# Two apks of same source, different package name, different signatures not installing

Tags: android, apk, code-signing

I have a single source and want two different apks to be installed in a device. For this

- I sign the source with two different keystores
- change the package name for all the files and also the AndroidManifest.xml packageName entries for the second apk.

Still I'm not able to install the second app when the first app is already installed.

I'm not using any IDE to build and sign instead doing it in terminal with "build" and "jarsigner" commands

Comment: Is the source code build is based on Android Studio ?or any other ?

Comment: The signature doesn't make any difference.  The java package names don't matter either.  What matters is the application id that you defined in the gradle build.  Those must be different.  What exactly are they for each app?